# User Account Control and Properties

Tags: powershell, attributes, ldap

I have run 2 different ways of checking whether user can change the password or not. First I used CMDLET to query and I got 12 of them are not able to change the password. Then I used the LDAP search by using `matching rule bit and` and it returned nothing. What's the reason here?

```
1. Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties CannotChangePassword| where {$_.CannotChangePassword} | sort-object {$_.samAccountName} | Select samAccountName
```

Total user cannot change the password is: 12

```
2. 

$domain = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain()    
$ADSearch = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher    
$ADSearch.SearchRoot ="LDAP://$domain"
$ADSearch.SearchScope = "subtree"
$ADSearch.PageSize = 100
$ADSearch.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))"    
$properies =@(
"sAMAccountName",
"userAccountControl"
)
foreach($pro in $properies)
{
    $ADSearch.PropertiesToLoad.add($pro)| out-null
    #the name of property of the object, search will load the name in an array #properties
}

$userObjects = $ADSearch.FindAll()
forEach ($user In $userObjects) 
{     
    $accountDis= $user.Properties.Item("userAccountControl")[0]
    $global:sam = $user.Properties.Item("sAMAccountName")[0]
    if( $accountDis -band 64){
        $passChange ="Not allowed"
        """$accountDis","$passChange"
    }       
}
```

Total user cannot change the password is: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For AD accounts, the "user cannot change password" is determined by the access control entry on the user account rather than the `ADS_UF_PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE` (0x40) bit in the `userAccountControl` attribute. (See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746448.aspx for more information.) The PowerShell cmdlets are clever enough to do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: so you mean the `ADS_UF_PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE` is not able to manipulate in this case? It would be nice if you can explain why I got 2 different results. And `userAccountControl` is replicated as well..